# For each value in a vector get the corresponding next smallest value

Tags: r, vector, lag

For each element in a vector, I want the corresponding next smaller value in the vector, without changing the original order of the elements.

For example, suppose the given vector is:

```r
c(4, 5, 5, 10, 3, 7)
```

Then the result would be:

```r
c(3, 4, 4, 7, 0, 5)
```

Note that since 3 does not have any smaller value, I want it to be replaced with 0.
Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use

```
sapply(v1, function(x) sort(v1)[match(x, sort(v1))-1][1])
[1]  3  4  4  7 NA  5
```

---

Or use a vectorized option

```
v2 <- unique(v1)
v3 <- sort(v2)
v4 <-  v3[-length(v3)]
i1 <- match(v1, v3) - 1
i1[i1 == 0] <- NA
v4[i1]
[1]  3  4  4  7 NA  5
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(4, 5, 5, 10, 3, 7)
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun for the quick response. This actually works perfectly but I have a lengthy vector of size 50000, so It takes a while for sapply to give me the answer. Is there a way to make it a little faster or do without the sapply? Thank you

Comment: @LindaA does the update works for you?

Comment: The updated method works really fast @ akrun. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `findInterval`:

```r
sx = sort(x)
i = findInterval(x, sx, left.open = TRUE)
sx[replace(i, i == 0, NA)]
# [1]  3  4  4  7 NA  5
```

Comment: Interesting `findInterval` solution, +1!

Answer (score 0):

We can try the code below using `outer` + `max.col`

```
> m <- outer(v, u <- sort(unique(v)), `>`)

> replace(u[max.col(m, ties.method = "last")], rowSums(m) == 0, NA)
[1]  3  4  4  7 NA  5
```

Comment: This also works, but it is a little slower than what @akrun updated

Comment: @LindaA yes, it is slow especially when you have large `v` due to `outer`